# After placing a shipment using FedEx Sandbox APIs, I'm able to get the tracking number from response, But unable to track with that tracking number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fedex

I'm using the following FedEx sandbox API

`https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/ship/v1/shipments`

and able to get the response which contains the tracking number.

But when I'm using that tracking number in the

`https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/track/v1/trackingnumbers`

API getting the following error as  **TRACKING.TRACKINGNUMBER.NOTFOUND**.

```
{
    "transactionId": "b06f2eb2-8cdf-4139-83b7-1a6eccffed56",
    "output": {
        "completeTrackResults": [
            {
                "trackingNumber": "794693611559",
                "trackResults": [
                    {
                        "trackingNumberInfo": {
                            "trackingNumber": "794693611559",
                            "trackingNumberUniqueId": "",
                            "carrierCode": ""
                        },
                        "error": {
                            "code": "TRACKING.TRACKINGNUMBER.NOTFOUND",
                            "message": "Tracking number cannot be found. Please correct the tracking number and try again."
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But when I'm using the Mock tracking numbers provided by the FedEx for testing able to get the following response.

```
{
    "transactionId": "3b56ae53-83fa-47f5-83d6-ec1ca6aeff3a",
    "output": {
        "completeTrackResults": [
            {
                "trackingNumber": "449044304137821",
                "trackResults": [
                    {
                        "trackingNumberInfo": {
                            "trackingNumber": "449044304137821",
                            "trackingNumberUniqueId": "12013~449044304137821~FDEG",
                            "carrierCode": "FDXG"
                        },
                        "additionalTrackingInfo": {
                            "nickname": "",
                            "packageIdentifiers": [
                                {
                                    "type": "GROUND_SHIPMENT_ID",
                                    "values": [
                                        "DMWsGWdnN"
                                    ],
                                    "trackingNumberUniqueId": "",
                                    "carrierCode": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "CUSTOMER_REFERENCE",
                                    "values": [
                                        "115380173"
                                    ],
                                    "trackingNumberUniqueId": "",
                                    "carrierCode": ""
                                }
                            ],
                            "hasAssociatedShipments": false
                        },
                        "shipperInformation": {
                            "address": {
                                "city": "JEFFERSONVILLE",
                                "stateOrProvinceCode": "IN",
                                "countryCode": "US",
                                "residential": false,
                                "countryName": "United States"
                            }
                        },
                        "recipientInformation": {
                            "address": {
                                "city": "Miami",
                                "stateOrProvinceCode": "FL",
                                "countryCode": "US",
                                "residential": false,
                                "countryName": "United States"
                            }
                        },
                        "latestStatusDetail": {
                            "code": "OC",
                            "derivedCode": "IN",
                            "statusByLocale": "Initiated",
                            "description": "Shipment information sent to FedEx",
                            "scanLocation": {
                                "city": "Miami",
                                "stateOrProvinceCode": "FL",
                                "countryCode": "US",
                                "residential": false,
                                "countryName": "United States"
                            },
                            "ancillaryDetails": [
                                {
                                    "reason": "IN001",
                                    "reasonDescription": "Please check back later for shipment status or subscribe for e-mail notifications",
                                    "action": "",
                                    "actionDescription": ""
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "dateAndTimes": [
                            {
                                "type": "ACTUAL_PICKUP",
                                "dateTime": "2016-08-01T00:00:00-06:00"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "SHIP",
                                "dateTime": "2020-08-15T00:00:00-06:00"
                            }
                        ],
                        "availableImages": [],
                        "packageDetails": {
                            "packagingDescription": {
                                "type": "YOUR_PACKAGING",
                                "description": "Package"
                            },
                            "physicalPackagingType": "PACKAGE",
                            "sequenceNumber": "1",
                            "count": "1",
                            "weightAndDimensions": {
                                "weight": [
                                    {
                                        "value": "3.0",
                                        "unit": "LB"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "1.36",
                                        "unit": "KG"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "dimensions": [
                                    {
                                        "length": 14,
                                        "width": 11,
                                        "height": 5,
                                        "units": "IN"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "length": 35,
                                        "width": 27,
                                        "height": 12,
                                        "units": "CM"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "packageContent": []
                        },
                        "shipmentDetails": {
                            "possessionStatus": true
                        },
                        "scanEvents": [
                            {
                                "date": "2013-12-30T13:24:00-05:00",
                                "eventType": "OC",
                                "eventDescription": "Shipment information sent to FedEx",
                                "exceptionCode": "",
                                "exceptionDescription": "",
                                "scanLocation": {
                                    "streetLines": [
                                        ""
                                    ],
                                    "postalCode": "471307761",
                                    "countryCode": "US",
                                    "residential": false,
                                    "countryName": "United States"
                                },
                                "locationType": "CUSTOMER",
                                "derivedStatusCode": "IN",
                                "derivedStatus": "Initiated"
                            }
                        ],
                        "availableNotifications": [],
                        "deliveryDetails": {
                            "deliveryAttempts": "0",
                            "deliveryOptionEligibilityDetails": [
                                {
                                    "option": "INDIRECT_SIGNATURE_RELEASE",
                                    "eligibility": "INELIGIBLE"
                                },
                                {
                                    "option": "REDIRECT_TO_HOLD_AT_LOCATION",
                                    "eligibility": "INELIGIBLE"
                                },
                                {
                                    "option": "REROUTE",
                                    "eligibility": "INELIGIBLE"
                                },
                                {
                                    "option": "RESCHEDULE",
                                    "eligibility": "INELIGIBLE"
                                },
                                {
                                    "option": "RETURN_TO_SHIPPER",
                                    "eligibility": "INELIGIBLE"
                                },
                                {
                                    "option": "DISPUTE_DELIVERY",
                                    "eligibility": "INELIGIBLE"
                                },
                                {
                                    "option": "SUPPLEMENT_ADDRESS",
                                    "eligibility": "INELIGIBLE"
                                }
                            ],
                            "destinationServiceArea": "OC"
                        },
                        "originLocation": {
                            "locationContactAndAddress": {
                                "address": {
                                    "city": "JEFFERSONVILLE",
                                    "stateOrProvinceCode": "IN",
                                    "countryCode": "US",
                                    "residential": false,
                                    "countryName": "United States"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "lastUpdatedDestinationAddress": {
                            "city": "Miami",
                            "stateOrProvinceCode": "FL",
                            "countryCode": "US",
                            "residential": false,
                            "countryName": "United States"
                        },
                        "serviceCommitMessage": {
                            "message": "The delivery date may be updated when FedEx receives the package.",
                            "type": "SHIPMENT_LABEL_CREATED"
                        },
                        "serviceDetail": {
                            "type": "GROUND_HOME_DELIVERY",
                            "description": "FedEx Home Delivery",
                            "shortDescription": "HD"
                        },
                        "standardTransitTimeWindow": {
                            "window": {
                                "ends": "2014-01-02T00:00:00-06:00"
                            }
                        },
                        "estimatedDeliveryTimeWindow": {
                            "window": {}
                        },
                        "goodsClassificationCode": "",
                        "returnDetail": {}
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Please help me with this, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use a real tracking number in the test environment it doesn't work... you need to move to the production environment.
https://apis.fedex.com/track/v1/trackingnumbers